# Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query though the time hasn't exceeded the limit

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, error-code

I get an error saying 'Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query' when I work on Workbench. I increased the limit from 600 seconds to 6000 seconds. However, it loses connection way before 100 seconds. I'm using Workbench 6.1. My syntax has no issues with it since I tried on fiddle by creating a sample, small-sized table.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify exactly which limit parameter you increased. According to [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-lost-connection.html), It seems that the most suitable configuration option for this is `net_read_timeout` on MySQL server (default 30 sec). Also, check the rest of the recommendations there.